" Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Did not find functions with language [java]." Couldn't able to run function app Blob trigger in LOCAL using JAVA
**I am trying to run my function app Blob trigger in my local . installed core tools and host.json,local.settings.json are configured for local . got this error , here is my class and json files.**

public class BlobTrigger {
/**
* This function will be invoked when a new or updated blob is detected at the specified path. The blob contents are provided as input to this function.
*/
@FunctionName("BlobTriggerJava")
@StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")
public void process(
@BlobTrigger(name = "BlobTrigger", path = "mycontainer/{name}", dataType = "binary") String content,
@BindingName("name") String filename,
final ExecutionContext context
) {
context.getLogger().info("Java Blob trigger function processed a blob. Name: " + filename + "\n  Size: " + content.length() + " Bytes");
}
}
**HOST.JSON-**



 {
      "version": "2.0",
      "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
      },
    }

**LOCAL.SETTINGS.JSON-**



 {
      "IsEncrypted": false,
      "Values": {
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java",
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "yuyoiuu",
        "JAVA_HOME": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11\\bin\\java.exe"
      }
    }
    

**ERROR**:
[2024-09-25T14:01:16.007Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation 'd5fc1da7-0896-422d-b0fb-4b7156b7cf44'.
[2024-09-25T14:01:16.007Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Did not find functions with language [java].
[2024-09-25T14:01:16.017Z] Failed to stop host instance 'b6edcdeb-bf79-45ac-87fa-ee90fd5a0549'.
[2024-09-25T14:01:16.017Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: The host has not yet started.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
[2024-09-25T14:01:16.051Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '24fd6af8-c37c-4ba0-9325-77bbdba9b29b'.
[2024-09-25T14:01:16.051Z] Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection: Cannot access a disposed object.
[2024-09-25T14:01:16.051Z] Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.
Function execute succeed.



"JAVA_HOME" path in your local.settings.json should point to the JDK root, not the java.exe binary

"JAVA_HOME": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11"

For maven application, you should have this below dependency.
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Replace the below code in the blobtriggerclass.
package com.function;

import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;

public class BlobTrigger {
    @FunctionName("BlobTriggerJava")
    @StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")
    public void process(
        @BlobTrigger(name = "BlobTrigger", path = "mycontainer/{name}", dataType = "binary") String content,
        @BindingName("name") String filename,
        final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java Blob trigger function processed a blob. Name: " + filename + "\n Size: " + content.length() + " Bytes");
    }
}

local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "JAVA_HOME": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11"
  }
}

Update the "version" to "2.0" or "3.0"
host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}

Result:


Don't think you can run it locally. You must deploy the function app on Azure and then add an object into the Blob to trigger it.
Please refer my article
